# Assign a time.Date to a *time.Time pointer to test a JSON deserialization

Tags: json, pointers, go

I have a struct, where one of the fields was declared as String, but it was intended to store a Time. Therefore I changed it to `*time.Time` ([see the commit](https://github.com/weppos/go-dnsimple/commit/1b6ea6f90f4724495b81cbc9fc0bb3c256e991da)), note the use of a pointer to bypass the issue where [`",omitempty"` doesn't really omit the value in case of an blank date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074105/123527).

So far so good. The problem is that now I'm trying to write a code that tests the correct deserialization of the JSON string, but I can't compare the result with

```
want := Record{Id: 1539, UpdatedAt: time.Date(2014, 01, 15, 22, 03, 04, 0, time.UTC)}
```

because `UpdatedAt` is expected to be a pointer `*time.Time`, whereas `time.Date` returns a `time.Time`.

I can't use

```
want := Record{Id: 1539, UpdatedAt: &time.Date(2014, 01, 15, 22, 03, 04, 0, time.UTC)}
```

because it is indeed rejected (it expects a pointer, I try to assign a struct)

```
cannot take the address of time.Date(2014, 1, 15, 22, 3, 3, 0, time.UTC)
```

Here's my question. Is there a way to create a `Record` with a `time.Date` on the fly (hence without assigning the `time.Date` to a variable and then get the pointer) and/or a workaround for the issue that guarantees I can have a proper nil value assigned when the object is serialized/deserialized and the date is blank?

Comment: usually time.Time and time.Date are used without pointers. check the package [time](http://golang.org/pkg/time). All the functions return the struct not the pointer to struct. You should do it too ;)

Comment: @fabrizioM I explained why the pointer is required. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074105/123527 Can you provide an alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't take the address of a function return value because you can only take the address of something that can be assigned to.

Think of it this way: if you store the result in variable, you can then take the address of that variable, but if you don't, then there's nothing you can take the address from.

Comment: Your answer explains the reason, which was already clear to me, but doesn't provide a solution. Can you provide a solution to the issue that guarantees the correct serialization/deserialization of the JSON object with an empty time?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, there isn't a different solution, you have to do what you wrote in the question: store the value in a variable and then reference that variable.

Answer (score 11):

You want to store the date value in a variable first and then use the pointer of the variable.

```
myDate := time.Date(2014, 01, 15, 22, 03, 04, 0, time.UTC)
want := Record{Id: 1539, UpdatedAt: &myDate}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, you can define a function like this:

```
func toTimePtr(t time.Time) *time.Time {
    return &t
}
```

And then do that:

```
want := Record{Id: 1539, UpdatedAt: toTimePtr(time.Date(2014, 01, 15, 22, 03, 04, 0, time.UTC))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the address of literals as they get inlined in the code (at least that's my current understanding of the reason).

I often have the following in my test code:

```
func literalAddressProvider[T any](s T) *T { return &s }
```

which works for any type (well, all those I have tried so far!). Eg `string` and `time.Time`.

You can also use the `ToPtr()` function of the [lo](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/samber/lo#section-readme) package on github (over 9k stars as I'm writing this post). This works the same, you can write `ptr := lo.ToPtr("hello world")` (the go compiler is able to infer `T` as string so no need to specify it, contrary to the many examples that appear in the lo package docs).